# how to create template for foldable booklet (requires rotating and reordering pages)?

Tags: minipage, rotating, booklet

I'd like to create a template or package for documents that are printed on a single page but can be folded into a proper booklet like [this](http://experimentwithnature.com/03-found/experiment-with-paper-how-to-make-a-one-page-zine/):

[image]

I'd like, when writing a new document, to be able to write a document as normal and have the content automatically rendered into (up to) 8 appropriately ordered and oriented subpages at compile time.

I figured I could divide into 8 subpages with `minipage`, and make some of the minipages upside down with `rotating`, but this has two major limitations:

1. `minipage` doesn't allow setting a fixed height for a minipages
2. this wouldn't allow LaTeX to choose minipage breaks the way it normally chooses page breaks, as the author would have to pre-define content for each minipage separately

I also looked into `booklet`, but it doesn't seem right for this use case.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Print a normal PDF with 8 portrait pages, then in a new document use the pages of this document as images in a new landscape document without margins with the correspondent order and rotation (e.g.:   `\includegraphics[page=4,angle=180,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill\includegraphics[page=3, ....`. After the 4th image (page 1) add a line break  and the page 5 without rotation and so on. Ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

source.tex:

```
\documentclass[a6paper,20pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\parskip1em
\begin{document}
\sffamily\fontsize{160}{280}\selectfont
\centering
 Page\par \#1\newpage
 Page\par \#2\newpage
 Page\par \#3\newpage
 Page\par \#4\newpage
 Page\par \#5\newpage
 Page\par \#6\newpage
 Back\par Cover \newpage
 Front\par Cover\newpage
\end{document}
```

Booklet.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[page=4,angle=180,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill
\includegraphics[page=3,angle=180,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill
\includegraphics[page=2,angle=180,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill
\includegraphics[page=1,angle=180,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\\
\includegraphics[page=5,angle=0,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill
\includegraphics[page=6,angle=0,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill
\includegraphics[page=7,angle=0,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill
\includegraphics[page=8,angle=0,width=.24\paperwidth]{source.pdf}\hfill
\end{document}
```

Final output:

[image: mwe]

Comment: you might want to change the first `page=3` to `page=2` in the booklet code.  the method is correct, but the labeling is confusing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Solved!

Comment: Thanks @Fran, this is great. I'll note for those like me who are stuck with US paper sizes, the "a4paper" in Booklet.tex should be replaced with "letterpaper" and the "a6paper" in source.tex should be replaced with "paperheight=4.25in,paperwidth=2.75in".

Comment: Also, it's neat that since Booklet.tex takes in page images from an already-rendered full-page pdf, it could even be used to "zine-ify" a document prepared in a non-latex word processor.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but an article I have written, available at https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99glister.pdf describes some 10 different layouts for this kind of book (the article is too long to reproduce here). In the cases I describe it is really up to the author to specify what goes on each page. You might find something useful there.